# Phrase detection using PhrasesTransformer

Tags: nlp, gensim, n-gram, phrase

```
from gensim.sklearn_api.phrases import PhrasesTransformer

# Create the model. Make sure no term is ignored and combinations seen 3+ times are captured.
m = PhrasesTransformer(min_count=1, threshold=3)
text = [['I', 'love', 'computer', 'science', 'computer', 'science', 'is', 'my', 'passion', 'I', 'studied', 'computer', 'science']]

# Use sklearn fit_transform to see the transformation.
# Since computer and science were seen together 3+ times they are considered a phrase.
m.fit_transform(text)
```

The above code does return computer_science as expected. But What is the right method to extract phrases pragmatically?

Comment: What do you mean by "right way" and "pragmatically"? (The `Phrases` statistical technique works OK for a bunch of purposes, but will both miss phrases/concepts/entities a person would perceive, and combine multigrams that a person could tell, from context, aren't a real unit-of-meaning. So the results will often be unaesthetic for showing to users, but still helpful behind-the-scenes for things like classification or info-retrieval.)

Comment: Something like m.get_phrases() so it can return computer_science. I am not sure if there's such method or property that can do it

Comment: Do you mean, list *all* the possible phrases it's learned?

Comment: Exactly, I am not sure if there's such method or property as i am new to n-gram

Answer (score 0):

The `PhrasesTransformer` wraps an instance of gensim's `Phrases` model, which does the actual compilation of co-occurrence statistics & promotion of bigrams to phrases.

Unfortunately, the `Phrases` object does not, at least through `gensim-3.8.3` (April 2020), offer any list of all phrases it could emit. Essentially, it just compiles statistics, then when presented with *new* text, checks to see which bigrams should be combined (in accordance with its current stats & parameters).

Downsides of this approach include:

- lots of redundant re-calculations
- no handy list of "all" the possible phrases
- retains memory-consuming potential-phrases, that don't qualify with current scoring/threshold parameters, but might if those changed

Upsides of this approach include:

- changing scoring/threshold parameters can immediately enable new phrases

To actually get a list of the phrases a `Phrases` instance could create, you need to feed it text with all potential phrases, and see what it promotes. This should probably be a utility method on gensim `Phrases` – as a very similar enumeration is already done inside the associated `Phraser` class initialization – but isn't. Such a method could work roughly work like (this may have bugs as I haven't tested it):

```py
from gensim.models.phrases import pseudocorpus

def report_all_phrases(phrases_model):
    corpus = pseudocorpus(phrases_model.vocab, phrases_model.delimiter, phrases_model.common_terms)
    phrasegrams = set()
    for bigram, score in phrases_model.export_phrases(corpus, self.delimiter, as_tuples=True):
        phrasegrams.add(bigram)
    return phrasegrams
```